# Magento 2 - Change the product page layout only for configurable products

Tags: magento2, product, php, layout, configurable-product

I create the layout for simple products. `Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

Now I want to add this line:

```
 <move element="product.info" destination="content" before="-"/>
```

but only for configurable products.

How I can change the layout only for configurable products?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create layout file for configurable product,

```
catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml
```

Create above xml file inside layout folder and keep your code inside it.

Keep  `<move element="product.info" destination="content" before="-"/>`
content in above layout file.

Comment: Hi thanks, I create the layout I add the code, but the product.info block is still display on simple products

Comment: product.info is call in all product type so its display

Comment: what I want to do is to move that swatches at the bottom of the page

Comment: si if I move only product.info.options.wrapper the swatches is not work anymore. you have any idea? or how I can solve this?

Comment: you cant move only swatches to bottom of page because swatches coming inside form and after add to cart form data pass to controller so you have to keep it inside form.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Product type Specific layout file using below name:

```
catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml
```

Check more for this in Configurable Product Module:

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml